# VueJs 2 and ajax data. How start mount after recive data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2

I have data which loaded from server. I have one root app, and two child components. I want do loading in parent, then pass this data to child, and i did not want start mount while my child components did not recive data.

```
<router-view :results="results"></router-view>
```

Comment: i think you implement state management in your application using library like `vuex`

Comment: why you bind value to router-view?

Comment: i want get access to results by props in my components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way use in component after data was loaded:

```
this.$forceUpdate()
```